# Not enough spendable outputs error on MyMonero

Tags: transaction-confirmation, error-log, mymonero, chained-payments, change

Sometimes when I attempt to send multiple payments (totaling less than the sum of my balance) in a short period of time from MyMonero.com I receive the error message:

> Not enough spendable outputs

Why am I seeing this message, when I know that I have enough Monero to send the transactions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you send a Monero transaction the sum of the outputs used in the ring transaction will exceed the amount of your payment. Once the transaction is confirmed the change is returned to your wallet. Change like all incoming transactions is unlocked after 10 blocks.

Change:

> Monero sent as part of a transaction, but unique in that returns to your account instead of going to a recipient.

Monero does not support chained payments in the same block. Doing so would not be practical on chain. Off chain solutions would bring additional security and privacy concerns.

Comment: It is worth noting that this issue is not exclusive to MyMonero. The same principle would apply to transactions sent from simplewallet.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you mean "Monero does **NOT** support chained payments in the same block." , but I'm not 100% sure enough to edit it.

Comment: I've added the missing not.