# Help with sending on MyMonero

Tags: ring-signatures, mymonero, change

I just sent 6.9 monero from MyMonero, but it showed up as taking 10xmr out of my account instead of 6.9. On the receiving end it shows 6.9xmr as well. Where did the other 3.1 go?? Is that a "fee" taken by MyMonero? Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: It's back down to the original 6.9xmr. Just had a thought, is that a secuirty/privacy measure? Showing the blockchain a different ammount than was actually sent? I just checked the transaction on chainradar and it shows 10xmr as well. If so I think that's pretty cool.

Comment: Exact link of the website(mymonero....) ?

Comment: Heart attack over I guess.... Started at 10xmr, but after mashing f5 it's down to the original 6.9xmr. As for the website, I always double check, it was mymonero.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I just sent 6.9 Monero from MyMonero, but it showed up as taking 10xmr out of my account instead of 6.9.

What you described was not a mistake. It is related to how ring signatures are created and how you as the sender also are a recipient of some of the outputs.

This [related question](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/270/not-enough-spendable-outputs-error-on-mymonero/271#271) explains why your issue resolved itself:

> Once the transaction is confirmed the change is returned to your wallet. Change like all incoming transactions is unlocked after 10 blocks.

This change issue is not specific to [MyMonero.com](https://mymonero.com/#/). It applies to simplewallet the same way.